# Javascript function works correctly 8 times, then every other time

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, get, html-lists

I have a javascript function that I am trying to add to my document, to give it a sense of being updated in real time.  It is an AJAX call to my MVC controller which returns a JSON result and adds it to the list at the top, and then hides the last li, and then removes the last li.

The problem is, the function works flawlessly 8 times, and then goes screwy.  After the first 8 times, the function only hides the last item in the list, every other time it adds one to the top.  So after the first 8 runs, my list grows by 1 li every other run of the script:

Here is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function latestBranch() {
            $.getJSON("Home/LatestWristband", null, function (html) {
                var showHideSpeed = 200;
                var firstLI = $("#recentBranches ul li").first();
                if (firstLI.text() !== html) {
                    firstLI.before('<li>' + html + '<\li>');
                    $("#recentBranches ul li").first().hide().show(showHideSpeed);
                    $("#recentBranches ul li").last().hide(showHideSpeed / 4,
                        function () {
                            $("#recentBranches ul li").last().remove();
                        });
                }
            });
        };
        setInterval(latestBranch, 500);
    });
</script>
```

I have tried several things to get this to work.  My first thought is that the interval was quicker than the script was getting rid of the last list item, but I have tested this with a interval of 5000 for the get, and 1000 for the hide/show of the elements, which should provide an extra 3000ms at least before the next call.  I have also tried changing this:

```
$("#recentBranches ul li").last().hide(showHideSpeed / 4,
                        function () {
                            $("#recentBranches ul li").last().remove();
                        });
```

to:

```
$("#recentBranches ul li").last().remove();
```

however I get the same problem after 8 times.  It seems though that after it gets into this rhythm of only working every other time, it keeps it indefinetly.  I have tried looking aroudn, but I can't seem to find anything that would explain these symptoms...

Comment: Someone had suggested that I use setTimeout instead with a recursive option of the function calling itself after completing, with a delay.  I did try that, but have the same problem.  I have cleared the browser cache, and verified that the script in the browser is the one that I just changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong slash to close the `<li>`, which means you're actually adding 2 `<li>`s per request. (The second one is blank)

change this line:

```
firstLI.before('<li>' + html + '<\li>');
```

to this:

```
firstLI.before('<li>' + html + '</li>');
```

Comment: EXCELLENT!  Stupid mistake, should have caught it.  I guess the reason I didn't is because it did work 8 times before only every other.  I could understand the 8 times correct, as there are originally 7 items in the list, so when it removes the 7th, it was then to incorrect li's.  However, can you explain why it did work every other time?  If it only removed 7, and then kept adding in, but never removing, I could have caught that.  I find that really odd and interesting!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see the 2 li's per request!  I have marked your answer correct though, and up'ed it!  Thanks so much.